# Spring-Core-WS isn't compatible with Spring 4.3.15 is it?

Tags: java, spring, spring-ws

I received this below error while using the Spring web service with spring framework 4.3.15 version jars.

spring-ws-2.1.2.RELEASE-all.jar
spring-ws-core-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar

Can you let me know how we can resolve it do I need to upgrade spring ws jars or degrade spring framework version.

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionServiceFactory.createDefaultConversionService()Lorg/springframework/core/convert/support/GenericConversionService;
    at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.method.XPathParamMethodArgumentResolver.(XPathParamMethodArgumentResolver.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:142)
    ... 38 more

Comment: why are you using 2 different version of spring-ws?

Comment: You are mixing 2 different `spring-ws` versions, first of all stop doing that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are mixing two different versions,first resolve that and try if it won't go right then his question is already asked and already solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38703522/spring-core-ws-isnt-compatible-with-spring-4-3-0-is-it). You can get help from there.